# Как отображать посты по 4 штуки в одной строке

Tags: css

у меня на сайте (game-your .tk) посты отображаются одна штука в одной строке.
Мне надо сделать как на сайте (iwantgames.ru/bestgames) там посты отображаются по 3 штуки в одну строку или на другом сайте (androeed .ru/files/top-50-android-games.html) тут отображаются по пять в одной строке, или вот еще один (kanobu .ru/games/popular/) тут отображаются по 4 штуки в одной строке.
Как сделать это у меня на сайте вот на (ex ua) мой css файл (ex.ua/231461403126).
Подскажите какой код надо вставить и после какой строчки в моем коде.
Заранее спасибо...

Comment: я опять спрошу , сайт делался через artister ?

Comment: http://wordpress-theming.ru/themes/4-kolonki  вот 4х колоночные шаблоны

Answer (score 1):

Использовать grid сетку.

Можете взять готовую, например [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro).

Comment: и что отсюда нужно взять и куда вставить? Помоги, а то я тут слабо понимаю что, откуда и куда